# 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' on reading file no extension

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to read the chrome bookmark file within a windows 8 app. Problem is I am getting the 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' exception. So basically you have to register a file type association in the app manifest but the file has no extension.

File: `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks`

Is this even possible in windows 8 apps?

**UPDATE**

Here is my file access code:

```
 public async Task<string> ReadFile(string filename)
        {
            if (await FileExists(filename))
            {
                var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(filename);
                var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                var reader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream());
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            else return string.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: how are you trying to read the file? post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 app cannot access any random file system location. It can only access

- Application Folder (which is specific to your app)
- Common Folders like My Pictures, My Video and similar

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) article for complete details

Comment: Too bad, isn't there any workaround to get it work at least on my local system?

Comment: @MUG4N no, there is no workaround for this. If there is, then it is a bug or security loop hole.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use the file picker.  This allows the end user to manually select files on the filesystem. Once you have the FileStorage object from the file picker, you can then open and read the file.

Optionally, you can then save the StorageFile for later use, meaning that your app can access the file later, without the end user having to select the file again.

More info on MSDN:

[File Open Picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465174.aspx)

[How to track recently used files and folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh972344%28v=win.10%29.aspx)

Comment: nice idea but you cannot choose this particular file because it's hidden within the AppData folder